# How do I fill a string array with empty objects?

Tags: java, arrays, program-entry-point

So I create the array that will hold a cd collection. The only problem is the maximum array size is 50, how do I fill the array with empty objects if there's 50 objects?:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
  {
    final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = 50;
    final String FILENAME = "Collection.txt";

    CDOutput out = new CDOutput();
    CDInput in = new CDInput();

    int count = 0;  // Counter to keep track of number of elements in the array
    int choice = 0; // Menu choice

    String[] songArray = new String[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE]; // Create array to hold song collection

    {
    songArray[0] = new String("");// Fill array with empty objects ????????
    songArray[1] = new String("");
    songArray[2] = new String("");
    songArray[3] = new String("");
    songArray[4] = new String("");
    songArray[5] = new String("");
    songArray[6] = new String("");
    songArray[6] = new String("");
    songArray[7] = new String("");
    songArray[8] = new String("");
    songArray[9] = new String("");
    songArray[10] = new String("");
    songArray[11] = new String("");
    songArray[12] = new String("");
    songArray[13] = new String("");
    songArray[14] = new String("");
    songArray[15] = new String("");
    songArray[16] = new String("");
    songArray[17] = new String("");
    songArray[18] = new String(""); //and so on......
    }
```

I know this cannot be correct...

EDIT (this truly was quite easy in hindsight):

```
String[] songArray = new String[50];
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    songArray[i] = new String("");
```

Comment: Keep doing the same thing 50 times.

Comment: Really? There's nothing more efficient? @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: why dint u created dynamic array ??it would be more efficient

Comment: @KamleshArya could you explain more?

Comment: Use loop, which goes from 0 to 50

Comment: ask user to input array size and if it is <=50 than create array of that much size.

Comment: Use a loop. See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm

Comment: @SeeTheC check edit. is this correct?

Comment: @KamleshArya check edit. is this correct?

Comment: @user3029836: Almost correct . Do this : for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    songArray[i] = new String("");

Comment: as SeeTheC said..its correct.nothing wrong in that.!

Comment: Don't call new String(""), use "" instead like this: songArray[i] = ""; It is better for performance because of Java's String literal pool.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays.fill() maybe can help you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Also, if you are using Apache Commons Lang, you can use [ArrayUtils.nulltoEmpty()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#nullToEmpty%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Arrays#fill`. For more details, check out the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html). A typical use is as follows:

```
String[] a = new String[5];
String stringToFillWith = "";
Arrays.fill(a, 0, a.length - 1, stringToFillWith);
```

*Edit*: The two numbers 0 and `a.length - 1` are the initial and final indices to be filled with the given value (in this case, `stringToFillWith`).

Answer (score 1):

In Java, whenever you initialize an array, the array will have some default value that "fills up" all of the newly formed array.  For numerical values, they are zero, and `null` for arrays storing objects:

- `boolean[]`: `false`
- `char[]`: `'\u0000'`
- `byte[]`, `short[]`, `int[]`, , `long[]` : `0`
- `double[]`, `float[]`. : `0.0`
- `String[]`, `Object[]`, etc. : `null`

If you want `songArray` to begin with only `null` values before they have "CDs" added, then no further work is needed.  If you want `songArray` to begin with all `""` values then use `Arrays.fill`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
....
String[] songArray = new String[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];
Arrays.fill(songArray, "");
```

Note that you can also easily do this manually using a `for` loop, rather than copying and pasting a line of code 50 times:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
{
    songArray[i] = "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is obviously for a class, and we haven't gone over Arrays.fill so I went with the `for` loop which is what we actually went over in class (the class I wasn't in, of course). But I will keep Arrays.fill in mind!